# Toctree Activates Current Page and Main Page on Sidebar

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sidebar, read-the-docs, toctree

There is no problem on de `index.rst` it seems as below:

[image: Sphinx RTD doc home page]

However, when I go to another page, in my case it is `annotation-module.rst`, the sidebar selects and shows both `index` and `annotation-module`, as seen below:

[image: Sphinx RTD sidebar shows both menus]

However, I want to have only *Annotation Module* page to be activated and show its subsections.

My `conf.py` only uses `html_theme` by looking for the `READTHEDOCS` environment variable as below:

```
if not on_rtd:  # only import and set the theme if we're building docs locally
    try:
        import sphinx_rtd_theme

        html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"
        html_theme_path = [sphinx_rtd_theme.get_html_theme_path()]
    except Exception:
        pass
```

My `index.rst`:

```
Welcome to exceptive's documentation!
=====================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   index
   annotation-module

Here I have some introductory text.
```

And `annotation-module.rst` doesn't even include any `toctree`,I only have sections under it.

So, how do I only activate current documents sections on sidebar?

[Here](https://github.com/erayerdin/exceptive/tree/so/51463166/docs/source) is the source directory of docs as requested by [Steve Piercy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2214933/steve-piercy).

---

## Environment

- Python 3.5
- Sphinx 1.7.6
- sphinx-rtd-theme 0.4.0

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), ideally a repo, but at least the directory tree of your docs and complete contents of `conf.py`, `index.rst`, and `annotation-module.rst`.

Comment: Added the directory of related branch as requested.

Answer (score 0):

So, I kinda solved the problem. The problem was with `sphinx-autobuild` somehow, which I didn't mention in the question.

I simply use `make html` every time I update my documentations and serve it with `node`'s `http-server`.

Also referencing `index` in `index.rst` creates a warning:

```
WARNING: self referenced toctree found. Ignored.
```

So, removing `index` from `toctree` solved my problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

I tried replacing `index` with `self`.

Example (index.rst):

```
Welcome to exceptive's documentation!
=====================================

.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :caption: Contents:

   self
   annotation-module

Here I have some introductory text.
```